# Can we have two or more website hosted on a computer with IIS

Tags: networking, website, iis-7, intranet

I have an Virtual machine which has R2 2008 with an website which just works fine.
I was wondering if there's any way we could host multiple websites on that server.
Since its virtual we can add couple nic's if we'd like so more IP's.

Any ideas how else we could achieve this ?

Thanks for replying and reading the question....

Comment: People do it all the time.  You don't need to have multiple network cars either.  There are lots of tutorials on how to configure a single installation of IIS for multiple websites.

Comment: what im trying to do is for example i have myintranet on the same server also how can I create myintranet2 on the same server?

Comment: Please read this http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/iis-features-and-vista-editions

Comment: @CrashOverride - I know what you want to do.  We just expect a certain amount of research on your part.

Comment: @Ramhound Well I understand that you didn't know that I already done my search except for some not-to-the-point results I got, I was hoping some out of box ways to do it. That's Fine, Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @CrashOverride - You asked if it was possible this indicates you found no articles saying it was possible which I find unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a comment, but too much info for a comment I think.

To create another site, open IIS

Right-click sites from left side and then click Add Web Site. Fill in the details...

That is it to add a new site to IIS.

You may run into other issues though, such as potential binding issues, permission issues, virtual sites/applications etc but, you will be able to research each point and if you get stuck *after* researching, then ask away!